# flag and summarize gaps per month in visit logs (churns)

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df that looks like this:

```
 visits ={'someID':[111,111,111,222,222,222,333,333],
           'Month':[1,3,5,1,2,4,3,4],
          'visits':[4,10,5,2,2,2,5,5]}
 df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(visits)


 someID        Month      Visits
 111           1          4
 111           3          10
 111           5          5
 222           1          2
 222           2          2
 222           4          2
 333           3          5
 333           4          5
```

The data frame should be interpreted as:

The user 111 visited the month 1 but churned on month 2 and returned on month 3, churned on month 4 and returned on 5.
The user 222 visited the month 1 and 2, churned on month 3 and returned on month 4
THe user 333 first visited on month 3 ( he shouldn't appear as churn on month 1 and 2).

What would be an efficient way of summarizing the number of churns per month and the number of new visits per month?
churn = has visited before but didn't visit the current month
new visit = first-time visit

desired output:(

```
 Month     Churns    New_visits  Totals
   2         1           0         1
   3         1           1         2
   4         1           0         2
   5         2           0         1
```

Comment: In your desired output, `Totals` for Month 2 should be 1, right?

Comment: that's right. For some reason I edited it to change that to 2..

Comment: Are the visits ordered in any particular way?

Comment: No, I just displayed it this way for demo purposes

Comment: @kostas any of the 3 solutions should be fine to run for 500K rows, what kind of hardware are you running this on?

Answer (score 1):

This solution is hackish and not optimized, but it may work fast enough for your purposes.

First, count the presence of each user ID per month using a `pivot_table`:

```py
df2 = df.pivot_table(columns='someID', 
                     index='Month', 
                     values='visits', 
                     aggfunc='count')
# df2:
#    someID 111 222 333
# Month         
#     1     1.0 1.0 NaN
#     2     NaN 1.0 NaN
#     3     1.0 NaN 1.0
#     4     NaN 1.0 1.0
#     5     1.0 NaN NaN
```

Create an empty DataFrame indexed by month number, ready to receive integer counts:

```py
result = pd.DataFrame(data=np.zeros(df2.shape[0]),
                      index=df2.index,
                      columns=['New_visits'],
                      dtype=np.int16)
```

In the first pivot-table DataFrame, label each month *before* each user's first visit with a non-NaN sentinel value, e.g., -1. Use each user's `first_valid_index` to count the number of new visitors for each month:

```py
for col in df2:
    fvi = df2[col].first_valid_index()
    df2.loc[df2[col].index < fvi, col] = -1
    result.loc[fvi, 'New_visits'] += 1
# df2
#    someID 111 222 333
# Month         
#     1     1.0 1.0 -1.0
#     2     NaN 1.0 -1.0
#     3     1.0 NaN 1.0
#     4     NaN 1.0 1.0
#     5     1.0 NaN NaN
```

For each row, count each NaN as a churn, and each positive value as a visitor:

```py
result['Churns'] = df2.isnull().sum(axis=1)
result['Totals'] = df2.gt(0).sum(axis=1)
# result
#       New_visits  Churns  Totals
# Month         
#     1         2       0       2
#     2         0       1       1
#     3         1       1       2
#     4         0       1       2
#     5         0       2       1
```

Comment: thanks for the effort. Your loop takes ages to run on my actual data I'm afraid. The approach is cool

Comment: @kostas, thanks for letting me know! Out of curiosity, how many rows are in your dataset?

Comment: Around 500K rows

Comment: @kostas, I see. For what it's worth, I simulated 500k and 1M rows of random-integer userIDs, month numbers from 0 to 60, and number of visits larger than 1. The total runtimes on my 2015 MacBook Pro were 40 seconds and 90 seconds, respectively.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach that tries to use more Python-y DataFrame-ish code as opposed to iterative loops. I'm not sure of the performance impact, but I would think DataFrame operations are faster than iterative operations. Anyway, let's get started:

We don't really need the visits column so we can drop that

```
df2 = df.drop('visits', axis=1)
```

Sort and group by month - the count in the group by is basically the totals column

```
df2 = ( df2.sort_values(['Month'])
        .groupby(['Month']) 
        .agg(lambda x: list(x)) # convert the unique visitors in this month into a list
        .rename(columns={'someID':'visitors_this_month'}) )

#           visitors_this_month
# Month                    
# 1              [111, 222]
# 2                   [222]
# 3              [111, 333]
# 4              [222, 333]
# 5                   [111]
```

We can keep track of all previously seen visitors by performing a cumulative sum of the list and then grabbing only the uniques by applying the set constructor

(This is sort of a trick since you can't add sets directly)

```
df2 = df2.assign(all_visitors=df2['visitors_this_month'].cumsum().apply(set))

#       visitors_this_month     all_visitors
# Month                                     
# 1              [111, 222]       {222, 111}
# 2                   [222]       {222, 111}
# 3              [111, 333]  {333, 222, 111}
# 4              [222, 333]  {333, 222, 111}
# 5                   [111]  {333, 222, 111}
```

Python being Python I suppose, but you *can* subtract sets and we can determine the churns column by subtracting the set of visitors seen this month with the set of all previously seen visitors

```
df2 = df2.assign(visitors_this_month=df2['visitors_this_month'].apply(set))
df2 = df2.assign(Churns=df2['all_visitors']-df2['visitors_this_month'])
```

We can determine new visitors by subtracting the set of all previously seen visitors in the previous month from the set of visitors seen this month

```
df2 = df2.assign(New_visits=df2['visitors_this_month'] - df2['all_visitors'].shift())

#       visitors_this_month     all_visitors      Churns New_visits
# Month                                                            
# 1              {222, 111}       {222, 111}          {}        NaN
# 2                   {222}       {222, 111}       {111}         {}
# 3              {333, 111}  {333, 222, 111}       {222}      {333}
# 4              {333, 222}  {333, 222, 111}       {111}         {}
# 5                   {111}  {333, 222, 111}  {333, 222}         {}
```

We can drop the tracking column of all visitors now since we're done with it, and also the Month 1 row

```
df2 = df2.drop('all_visitors', axis=1)
df2 = df2.drop(df2.index[0])
```

Since we're only interested in the counts of each of these sets we can apply the len constructor to every element in the DataFrame

```
df2 = df2.applymap(len)
```

We can clean up the final DataFrame

```
df_final = df2.rename(columns={'visitors_this_month':'Totals'})
df_final = df_final[['Churns', 'New_visits', 'Totals']]
```

And that should be it!

```
# df_final
#            Churns  New_visits  Totals
# Month                            
# 2           1           0       1
# 3           1           1       2
# 4           1           0       2
# 5           2           0       1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach that should work.

First, in order to detect churn, we need to reindex, so that churn months are represented by `NaN` values. To do so first generate tuples of lists (which will next be used to create a MultiIndex):

```
# get the last month for which data is available
# to define a boundary for reindexing
end_month = df['Month'].max()

index_tuples = df.groupby('someID').apply(lambda x: \
    (np.repeat(x['someID'].unique(), (end_month + 1) - x['Month'].min()), \
        np.arange(x['Month'].min(), end_month + 1)))

# someID
# 111    ([111, 111, 111, 111, 111], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
# 222    ([222, 222, 222, 222, 222], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
# 333                    ([333, 333, 333], [3, 4, 5])
```

Next, zip the lists into ID-Month pairs, and then flatten the list and pass it into `pd.MultiIndex`:

```
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples( \
    [item for sublist in index_tuples.apply( \
       lambda x: zip(*x)).tolist() for item in sublist], \
     names=['someID', 'Month'])
# MultiIndex(levels=[[111, 222, 333], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]],
#            labels=[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4]],
#            names=[u'someID', u'Month'])
```

..and create a new DataFrame that's reindexed with the MultiIndex (instead of creating a copy of `df`, alternatively assign back to `df`):

```
df2 = df.set_index(['someID', 'Month']).reindex(index).reset_index()
#     someID  Month  visits
# 0      111      1     4.0
# 1      111      2     NaN
# 2      111      3    10.0
# 3      111      4     NaN
# 4      111      5     5.0
# 5      222      1     2.0
# 6      222      2     2.0
# 7      222      3     NaN
# 8      222      4     2.0
# 9      222      5     NaN
# 10     333      3     5.0
# 11     333      4     5.0
# 12     333      5     NaN
```

Finally, create a column to track new visits like so:

```
df2.loc[df2.groupby('someID').apply(lambda x: x.first_valid_index()), "New_visits"] = 1
#     someID  Month  visits  New_visits
# 0      111      1     4.0         1.0
# 1      111      2     NaN         NaN
# 2      111      3    10.0         NaN
# 3      111      4     NaN         NaN
# 4      111      5     5.0         NaN
# 5      222      1     2.0         1.0
# 6      222      2     2.0         NaN
# 7      222      3     NaN         NaN
# 8      222      4     2.0         NaN
# 9      333      3     5.0         1.0
# 10     333      4     5.0         NaN
```

...and use this `groupby` expression to get the monthly counts of churns & new visits:

```
df2.groupby('Month').agg( \
{'visits': lambda x: x.isnull().sum(), 'New_visits':sum}).rename( \
columns={'visits': 'Churn'})
#        Churn  New_visits
# Month                   
# 1        0.0         2.0
# 2        1.0         NaN
# 3        1.0         1.0
# 4        1.0         NaN
# 5        2.0         NaN
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort. I am still running it on my actual data and its a bit slow. The month 5 should be Churns 2 and New_visits 0. Is it a type or there some issue with the code?

Comment: See the revised answer, which will account for lag months following the last month a given user visited.

Comment: I think there is some mistake on the churn calculations as the numbers dont add up.

Comment: Don't add up to what? The logic being applied in this answer is pretty straightforward: if, after appearing once, "someID" is missing for a subsequent month, insert a row (where "visits" will be `NaN`). Then group by month and count the `NaN` values to get the count of churn events by month. Consider revising your question to provide a more representative sample of your full data & target output.